# How to get images from instagram feed that are on horizontal scroll with mvc and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get instagram feed with the help of instagram api and i am able to get all single image but problem is if there are multiple images are uploaded at a time like album then i can't able to get that multiple images and rather than images i got null.Here is my code.

Here i include method

```
 private InstagramRecentMediaResponse GetInstagramRecentMediaResponse()
    {
        try
        {
            var instagram = InstagramService.CreateFromAccessToken(AccessToken);
            return instagram.Users.GetRecentMedia(UserId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.Message, new NopException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here is my controller action for public view.

```
         try
        {
            string key = string.Format(INSTAGRAM_FEED_DATA_KEY, "FeedData", _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
            InstagramRecentMediaResponse media = _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
            {
                     return GetInstagramRecentMediaResponse();
            });

            if (media != null && media.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                foreach (InstagramMedia instagramMedia in media.Body.Data)
                {
                    if (instagramMedia != null && instagramMedia.Type.Equals("image", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        model.InstagramMedias.Add(instagramMedia);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(INSTAGRAM_FEED_DATA_PATTERN_KEY);

                if (media == null)
                {
                    _logger.Error("Instagram feed media is null");
                }
            }
```

Comment: which if statement or try-catch method throws out the null value?

Comment: we are not getting null at try-catch block but when we are debuging it then we are getting null at media.Body.Data